# Using using System.Windows.Media; and microsft.xna.framework.color together?

Tags: c#, xna

What I am attempting to do is create a popup in xna using silverlight, but it is throwing an error saying that there is ambiguity with the reference of 'system.windows.media.color' and 'Microsoft.xna.framework.color', is there a solution to this...if so any suggestions would be very useful.

EDIT:

Ok That has worked but I have now another problem, an error is coming up saying the 'Element is already the child of another element'....can anyone help me here? The error is thrown when it gets to the ' myStackPanel.Children.Add(txtNameEntry);' line...

```
  Border border = new Border();
                    border.BorderBrush = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.White);
                    border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(10);

                    StackPanel myStackPanel = new StackPanel();
                    myStackPanel.Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Black);

                    //Textblock containing the name you input and its properties.
                    //txtNameEntry.Text = Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceName").ToString();
                    txtNameEntry.Text = "Player 1";
                    txtNameEntry.Width = 350;
                    txtNameEntry.Height = 100;
                    txtNameEntry.MaxLength = 10;
                    txtNameEntry.FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Comis Sans MS");
                    txtNameEntry.FontSize = 48.0;
                    //txtNameEntry.Foreground = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily(Colors.Orange);
                    txtNameEntry.Foreground = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Orange);
                    txtNameEntry.Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.LightGray);
                    txtNameEntry.BorderBrush = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.LightGray);

                    //The ok button, which then allows you to procede into the game.
                    Button btnNameEntryOK = new Button();
                    btnNameEntryOK.Content = "Ok";
                    btnNameEntryOK.Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Orange);
                    btnNameEntryOK.FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Comic Sans Ms");
                    btnNameEntryOK.FontSize = 25.0;
                    btnNameEntryOK.Width = 180;
                    btnNameEntryOK.Height = 70;
                    btnNameEntryOK.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnNameEntryOK_Click);
                    btnNameEntryOK.Margin = new Thickness(10);

                    //Place these in the order you want them to be renderd to the screen.
                    myStackPanel.Children.Add(txtNameEntry);
                    myStackPanel.Children.Add(btnNameEntryOK);
                    border.Child = myStackPanel;
                    nameEntry.Child = border;

                    //set screen position of pop up 
                    nameEntry.VerticalOffset = 100.0;
                    nameEntry.HorizontalOffset = 50.0;

                    //open pop up
                    nameEntry.IsOpen = true;
```

XAML:

```
  <phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="MazeEscapePhoneSilveright.GamePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="480"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">

    <!--No XAML content is required as the page is rendered entirely with the XNA Framework-->
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an ambiguity because of namespace imports via the `using` directive, then you can use the full namespace for the proper `Color` object as appropriate.

I'm not sure which one you need to use exactly for the member in your code since you haven't posted it, but instead of just using `Color` use:

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.YOUR_MEMBER_CALL
```

or

```
System.Windows.Media.Color.YOUR_MEMBER_CALL
```

Alternatively, you can remove either `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;` or `using System.Windows.Media;` directive from the top of your file; whichever is most appropriate. Any *other* types you had used in the removed namespace will have to be updated to include the full (or partial) namespace to qualify their name though.

One final option is you can specify a [namespace alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). So for example, if you want to have a special call for the Silverlight colours, you might add to the top of your file:

```
using SilverlightMedia = System.Windows.Media;
```

Then later in the code you can have:

```
var myColor = SilverlightMedia.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);
```

Comment: Ah ok yes this has worked....but just one more problem in one line i have fontfamily, and colors declared....but this line txtNameEntry.Foreground = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Orange); does not work.How would I do it so that i can set the fontfamily, and the color of the textbox?

Comment: The `Foreground` property takes a brush, not a `FontFamily`. So you might have something like: `txtNameEntry.Foreground = new System.Windwos.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Orange);` EDIT: Then you'd have a _second_ line specifying the font family: `txtNameEntry.FontFamily = new System.Windows.MEdia.FontFamily("Arial");`

Comment: Right ok that has helped me thanks, i now have another problem which has been presented to me....please see edit thanks

Comment: Might want to ask a new question for that, your original has already been answered.